# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on SharePoint breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  8          6
Users destroyed                                   6          0
Users deleted                                     6          0
Users contacted                                  15          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           582      3,153
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               74        278
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        276      3,816
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              199      1,380
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               415      4,064
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              291      1,572
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          4
Questions reopened                               49          7
Questions protected                               4         31
Questions migrated                                3          0
Questions flagged⁴                                3        406
Questions closed                                462        219
Question flags handled⁴                         165        244
Posts unlocked                                    0          1
Posts undeleted                                  24         92
Posts locked                                      0         74
Posts deleted⁵                                  997      3,529
Posts bumped                                      0      8,724
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                                7          0
Comments flagged                                  0      1,684
Comments deleted⁶                               558      2,213
Comment flags handled                           437      1,247
Answers flagged                                 253      3,142
Answer flags handled                          2,239      1,156
All comments on a post moved to chat             27          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 2):

Happy new year! Thanks for the update and continued moderation. Interesting stats.

Comment: Hopefully the bot stops bumping this post now that I've given your answer a single upvote :P

Comment: Weird. Sorry to hear that.